# Does Git sees windows env variables?

Tags: git, cmd

I have 2 enviroment variables in windows *commitLast* and *commitSuc* which are commits hashes and I try to call from windows cmd:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an %aE" %commitLast%..%commitSuc% | sort | uniq
```

But windows says *Unknown option: --pretty=format:%aE* .

But when I call:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an %aE" 52a361527192bfd63b9b5247822b7031febd1d2d..f0fd5da91c7bc29634c220479ffa2b8af6ab7a02 | sort | uniq
```

It gives me atuhors of changes and their emails as expected.

When I  call git does somehow changes or may be use another set of enviroment variables ? How can I workaround it?

EDIT !!! :

Look like I missspelled command... It works fine now.

Comment: This looks more like a shell issue than a git issue. What shell are you using ?

Comment: I am using bash

Comment: To use environment variables in the bash shell use `$VARIABLE` instead of `%VARIABLE%`.